# How to validate 365 office accounts from my application

Tags: java, spring, office365

A while ago I developed an application. It has its own **registration and **authentication** of users.

Now as an improvement it is necessary to integrate the authentication of users can access if they wish through the personal account of **office 365**.

So, in what way could you perform this functionality. I have recently researched the office 365 APIs and also seen the documentation of the same and so far I have not found any documentation related to this case.

Note that the application is developed in **java** using **spring framework.**

Comment: Office 365, provides you management console where you can genereate key for communication channel, after that using that key you can make requests to API to check user credentials, here is link that explains this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis

Comment: Thank´s. I saw also exist EWS Java API , this api can validate credentials of office 365 account and send emails. 
But my only need is to validate the correct credentials and allow corrections to enter my application.